# Select Poorly Used Start and End Dates From Facility Table

Tags: sql, db2, logic

I'm using DB2, although a solution using any flavor of SQL would likely be easy enough for me to convert.

I didn't design this database, or the application that uses the database.  I haven't the power to change this application, how it works, or the data.  Because it defies what I consider to be conventional use of a start and an end date, I am struggling with writing something as simple as a select for a specific point in time.

Here are the relevant/edited parts of the table:

```
OBJECTID    FACILITY_ID     START_DATE      END_DATE    FACILITY_NAME
1001        500             1/1/1980        5/1/2000    Really Old Name
1002        500             1/1/1980        1/1/2006    Old Name
1003        500             1/1/1980        null        Current Name
1004        501             1/1/1980        3/1/2008    Closed Facility Name
1004        502             1/1/1980        null        Another Current Name
```

What I want to return, are the records which are valid for 7/1/2005:

```
OBJECTID    FACILITY_ID     START_DATE      END_DATE    FACILITY_NAME
1002        500             1/1/1980        1/1/2006    Old Name
1004        501             1/1/1980        3/1/2008    Closed Facility Name
1004        502             1/1/1980        null        Another Current Name
```

I'm trying to avoid subselects, but understand they may be necessary.  If I do need a subselect, I'd like to keep it limited to one.  Looking between the start and end date doesn't work, because it doesn't return facilities which have only one record with a null end date. Adding an OR condition to include end dates which are null may return more than one record in some cases.  This problem seems so simple on the service, that I must be missing a ridiculously obvious solution.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You say "Adding an OR condition to include end dates which are null may return more than one record in some cases."  In those cases, what is the correct behavior?

Comment: In the example you include, START_DATE is largely meaningless.  Is that the way the actual data is?

Comment: what if you had another facility id 500 with an end date of 1/1/2007. would you want to see that one instead of the 1/1/2006 date?

Comment: What I want to do is time travel, to the record that was valid for that point in time.  For facility id 500, I want to return the record that was valid as of 7/1/2005 which would be OBJECTID 1002.

Yes, the Start Date is, unfortunately, meaningless, and this is really how the data is.

Comment: "are the records which are valid for 7/1/2005" I don't understand this. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

would this work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE START_DATE < '7/1/2005' AND (END_DATE > '7/1/2005' OR END_DATE IS NULL);
```

Comment: That would return 2 records for FACILITY_ID 500.  The current record (which I don't want) along with the record which was valid for 7/1/2005 (which is the record I want)

Comment: oh i see.  i put another comment on your question for clarification.  looks like if more than one record is returned with the same facility id, you want the one with the maximum end date, right?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to coalesce the end date to the next day, :) Coalesce basically replaces a null value with the second parameter.  Pretty cool little trick.

```
select * from TAble where START_DATE < @DATE and Coalesce(END_DATE, @DATE+1) > @DATE
```

Comment: Coalesce is definitely a big hint, and I think the solution will use it.  However, this still returns the record valid for 7/1/2005 along with the new (null end date) record.

Answer (score 1):

Take 2:

```
select OBJECTID, FACILITY_ID, START_DATE, FACILITY_NAME, MIN(END_DATE) as  END_DATE
from facitities
where START_DATE <= @my_date and (@mydate <= END_DATE or END_DATE is null)
group by OBJECTID, FACILITY_ID, START_DATE, FACILITY_NAME
```

Comment: With OBJECTID, it would return all of the records.  However if I remove this and combine it with the Coalesce above......hmmmm

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer my own question.  Thanks all, the answers given were very helpful.  It was also helpful to think about exactly what I was trying to accomplish.  Combining concepts from the answers that were given, I was able to come up with something that seems to work:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    FACILITY_TABLE
WHERE 
    (END_DATE IS NULL
     AND OBJECTID NOT IN 
     (SELECT A.OBJECTID FROM FACILITY_TABLE A 
     WHERE '7/1/2005' BETWEEN A.BEGINDATE AND A.ENDDATE))
  OR 
    '7/1/2005' BETWEEN FACILITY_TABLE.START_DATE AND FACILITY_TABLE.ENDDATE
```

Since the start date was made meaningless by the data, I didn't include it.  The returns only the records that were valid back in 7/1/2005 without also including the current record if a record was expired between now and then.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've given us, this is what you want:

```
select * from facitities
where START_DATE <= @my_date and (@mydate <= END_DATE or END_DATE is null)
```

however, I suspect you knew that, and want something different, in which case, you'll have to be more specific about what's wrong with the data.

Comment: This returns 2 records for facility id 500 in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on the above:

```
select * from facilities
where @my_date between START_DATE AND COALESCE(END_DATE, CURRENT DATE)
```